# Are nested parentheses allowed in function type alias declaration?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, compiler-specific, alias-declaration

The following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/z7Ph9q9o4) can be compiled with gcc-13 and clang-16, but MSVC reports multiple errors

```
using foo_type = void ((((int, const char*))));   // (1)
// Compiler messages for line (1):
//    clang-16: ok.
//    gcc-13:   ok.
//    MSVC-v19: error C2062: type 'int' unexpected.


foo_type foo;

int main()
{
    foo(5, "Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: who's right? Does the Standard allow `alias-declaration` of a function type with multiple nested parentheses around argument list, like attempted in the example above?

Comment: Was MSVC compiled with `/permissive-`?

Comment: @Eljay MSVC rejects this code with `/permissive-` as well: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/P43jPMT4P).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is allowed and not specific to alias declarations. It applies to all declarators.

You can generally put as many parentheses around a declarator as you want. In the case of an *abstract-declarator* such as here, nothing changes, except that the *declarator-id* (i.e. the name) is omitted. An exception are declarators with a trailing-return-type.

For example, the following is also valid:

```
void (((foo(int, const char*))));

int main()
{
    foo(5, "Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

For the same reason you can also add parentheses around the `*` *abstract-declarator* in the function parameter:

```
using foo_type = void ((((int, const char(((*)))))));
```

Specifically for the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag, see the grammar production `( ptr-declarator )` for [`noptr-declarator`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.dcl#nt:noptr-declarator) in the non-abstract case and `( ptr-abstract-declarator )` for [`noptr-abstract-declarator`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.dcl#nt:noptr-abstract-declarator) in the abstract case.

Comment: I don't see how these productions permit extra parentheses around _parameters-and-qualifiers_.  We have a single pair from **_parameters-and-qualifiers_ ⟶ `(` _parameter-declaration-clause_ `)` _cv-qualifier-seq_? …**, but no opportunity within _parameter-declaration-clause_ to introduce additional pairs.

Comment: @TobySpeight _alias-declaration_ → `using` _identifier_ `=` _defining-type-id_ ;  _defining-type-id_ → _defining-type-specifier-seq_ _abstract-declarator_ ; _defining-type-specifier-seq_ → … → `void` ; _abstract-declarator_ → _ptr-abstract-declarator_ → _noptr-abstract-declarator_ → `(` _ptr-abstract-declarator_ `)` → `(` _noptr-abstract-declarator_ `)` → `(` _parameters-and-qualifiers_ `)`

Comment: (Not) funny thing is that GCC accepts `using foo_type = auto ((((int, const char*) -> void)));`